# Calculating birthday from date of birth? (from a testing point of view)

Tags: ruby, date, testing

To calculate birthday `bday = Date.strptime("1980,6,10","%Y,%m,%d")` from a DOB you have to do something like this to take into account for leap years.

```
def age(dob)
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
# age(bday) => 34
```

My question is how is the above code, different from this:

```
def age2(dob)
   ((Date.today - dob)/365).to_f.floor
end
# age2(bday) => 34
```

As a developer, this kind of example is just terrifying because it introduces a dirty bug in your code if not careful.

So *how would you go about writing a proper test for this?*

Comment: Can you explain the age2 function?  It has me baffled!

Comment: @JohnC: AFAICS it is functionally equivalent to `((Date.today - dob)/365.0).floor` which will age you slightly faster than reality as it does not cope with leap years. For some reason OP multiplies by 365.0 then divides by 365 twice.

Comment: Thanks @NeilSlater sounds like I was right to be baffled :0)

Comment: Haha, I'm learning all about the rational number class now!

Answer (score 0):

Every year is actually longer than 365 by 0.242199 days.  So to get this error to be significant you can build it up to one year, or test the threshold case where the year is rounded up too early.

This script demonstrates both.  It uses the three version of age that you posted.

```
require 'date'
def age1(dob)
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end

def age2(dob)
   ((Date.today - dob)/(1.0/365.0)/365/365).floor
end

def age3(dob)
   ((Date.today - dob)/365.0).to_f.floor
end

year = Time.now.year - (1 / 0.242199)

now = Time.now.utc.to_date
bd = Date.new(year,now.month,now.day + 1);
puts "Testing Date: #{bd}"
puts "using age1 - #{age1(bd)}"
puts "using age2 - #{age2(bd)}"
puts "using age3 - #{age3(bd)}"

year = Time.now.year - (365 / 0.242199)
bd = Date.new(year,1,1)
puts "Testing Date: #{bd}"
puts "using age1 - #{age1(bd)}"
puts "using age2 - #{age2(bd)}"
puts "using age3 - #{age3(bd)}"
```

Output:

```
Testing Date: 2009-06-13
using age1 - 4
using age2 - 5
using age3 - 5
Testing Date: 0506-01-01
using age1 - 1508
using age2 - 1509
using age3 - 1509
```

Comment: Not sure how you're getting that output... I'm getting `puts age2(bd)
-5876786` So now you have me baffled. :)

Comment: I updated my answer so you can just cut and paste it.

Comment: So I still don't get the same output as you... => #<Date: 773269925-01-01 ((-j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):040:0> puts "Testing Date: #{bd}"
Testing Date: 773269925-01-01
=> nil
irb(main):041:0> puts "using age1 - #{age1(bd)}"
using age1 - -773267911
=> nil
irb(main):042:0> puts "using age2 - #{age2(bd)}"
using age2 - -5876786
=> nil
irb(main):043:0> puts "using age3 - #{age3(bd)}"
using age3 - -5876786

Comment: I amusing ruby version ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]

Comment: works on my macbook `ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]` but not on my PC.. Need to check the version